# A bizarre 3D projection in 2D for a sphere

Tags: 3d, projection

Projection picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YENxg.png

I want to project a point with coordinates (x,y,z) sitting on/inside a sphere to 2D coordinates on the screen according to the projection shown in the image. I originally thought this was something similar to cabinet projection, however when doing that, the ellipses representing circles on each plane were tilted.

It seems like the scaling for the depth axis changes with the distance from the origin of the coordinate system, but I'm not sure how.

How may I project a point in this way? (the point will never go outside the sphere)

Comment: Is the projection supposed to be on the oblique axis shown?  If so, do you have an equation for that axis?

Comment: I just need the perspective projection of a point with coordinates (x,y,z) to 2D coordinates (x',y') of my screen. I've updated the picture to show the direction of each axis.

Comment: But there is no screen in the picture.

Comment: The screen I want to project points to is my own computer screen. I included that picture because I haven't been able to find any sort of transformation that would render points in 3D to my 2D like the circles have been rendered.

$$
P\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
x+\frac{1}{2}z\\ 
y+\frac{1}{2}z\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I tried this transformation for a cabinet projection, but it didn't give me the same results as the picture.

Comment: The answer is going to depend on the angle the x-axis makes with the other 2 in the projection.  It is not clear what that is.

Comment: Ideally it would be 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, I'll use $(x, y, z)$ for the three-dimensional coordinates, and $(u, v)$ as the projected coordinates, with both coordinate systems having origin at the center of the picture, $u$ increasing right, and $v$ up.

$y z$ plane seems to correspond to $u v$ plane, but the projected unit $x$ axis vector varies rather oddly.  You see, if you draw the square $(1,0,1)$-$(1,0,-1)$-$(-1,0,-1)$-$(-1,0,1)$-$(1,0,1)$, it will be a parallelogram, with top and bottom edges horizontal, but sides tangent to the tall ellipse at the intersection of the two ellipses.  The positive $x z$ quadrant has the same area as the negative $x z$ quadrant in the projection!

Let's look at where each of the points $x, y, z \in -1, 0, +1$ project to.
$$\begin{array}{ccc|cc|l}
 x &  y &  z &  u &  v & \text{Comments} \\
\hline
 -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ~ \\
 -1 & -1 &  0 & -1 & +c & ~ \\
 -1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & ~ \\
 -1 &  0 & -1 & +c & -1 & ~ \\
 -1 &  0 &  0 & +b & +b & ~ \\
 -1 &  0 & +1 & +a & +1 & ~ \\
 -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & ~ \\
 -1 & +1 &  0 & +1 & +a & ~ \\
 -1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & ~ \\
  0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ~ \\
  0 & -1 &  0 & -1 &  0 & ~ \\
  0 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & ~ \\
  0 &  0 & -1 &  0 & -1 & ~ \\
  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  0 & ~ \\
  0 &  0 & +1 &  0 & +1 & ~ \\
  0 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & ~ \\
  0 & +1 &  0 & +1 &  0 & ~ \\
  0 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & ~ \\
 +1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & ~ \\
 +1 & -1 &  0 & -1 & -a & ~ \\
 +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & ~ \\
 +1 &  0 & -1 & -a & -1 & ~ \\
 +1 &  0 &  0 & -b & -b & ~ \\
 +1 &  0 & +1 & -c & +1 & ~ \\
 +1 & +1 & -1 & +1 & -1 & ~ \\
 +1 & +1 &  0 & +1 & -c & ~ \\
 +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & +1 & ~ \\
\end{array}$$
This has one possible solution,
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
u(x, y, z) & = ~ y - b x + x z^2 (2 b - c - a) / 2 \\
         ~ & + ~ x y^2 b + x y^2 z^2 (c + a - 2 b) / 2 \\
         ~ & + ~ x^2 z^2 (a - c) / 2 + x^2 y^2 z (c - a) / 2 \\
v(x, y, z) & = ~ z + b x ( z^2 - 1 ) + \\
         ~ & + x y^2 (c + a - 2 b)(z^2 - 1) / 2 \\
         ~ & + x^2 y (c - a)(z^2 - 1) / 2 \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

In order for the $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$ to be properly tangential to the ellipses, we need
$$c - a = \frac{2 r b}{\sqrt{1 - b^2}}$$
where $r$ is the width and height of the ellipses; to keep linearity, we need
$$a (1 + b) + c (1 - b) = 2 b$$
Combining these, we find that for reasonable $0 \lt b \lt r \lt 1$,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\displaystyle a &= b - \frac{b r \sqrt{1 - b^2}}{b + 1} \\
\displaystyle c &= b - \frac{b r \sqrt{1 - b^2}}{b - 1} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
with $0 \lt a \lt b \lt r \lt c \lt 1$.  The image suggests $r \approx 0.302$ and $b \approx 0.289$, which yield $a \approx 0.224$, $c \approx 0.406$, so that the mapping/projection is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
u(x, y, z) &= y - 0.289 x ( 1 - y^2 ) - 0.091 x^2 z (1 - y^2 ) - 0.026 x z^2 (1 - y^2 ) \\
v(x, y, z) &= z + 0.289 x (z^2 - 1) + 0.091 x^2 y (z^2 - 1) + 0.026 x y^2 (z^2 - 1) \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$

This mapping replicates the observed features, but it for sure isn't a normal 3D projection; it is some kind of transformation to odd curvilinear coordinate system...

The reason for this image, by the way, is simplicity: it is "sufficiently close" to a projection for humans to roughly understand it – we tolerate surprisingly large errors (on the order of 10% to 25%) and still "perceive" it, approximately.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since $y$ and $z$ are aligned to the axes, they will be mapped at a 1-1 relationship.  They leaves what to with $x$.  There are 2 angles that are relevant;  one is the angle that $x$ makes with the x-axis on the screen, which I will call $\theta$, and the other is the angle that the axis makes with the screen, which I will call $\phi$.  For example, if $\phi$ is perpendicular to the screen, the $x-$coordinate will be completely suppressed.  Looking at the picture, and picking appropriate trig functions yields the transformation:
$$(x,y,z) \rightarrow (y-x\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi},z+x\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi})$$

Comment: [Picture using that transformation](https://i.imgur.com/Zrr5ayQ.png). The perspective still seems to be unlike the image, as the projected circles appear tilted.

Comment: what are you using for the angles in that picture?

Comment: $\theta = -\pi/4, \phi = \pi/6$.